# Running updates on a production Linux server

Tags: linux, tomcat, amazon-ec2

Is it an acceptable practice to run linux updates (sudo yum update) on a production server running Tomcat in standalone mode while the web application is live?

The server is an AWS EC2 instance running Amazon Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is acceptable to me, and I think it is to most people. There is always a small chance that something will go wrong when you install updates, but what is the alternative? I don't think that stopping Tomcat will help much.

If Tomcat itself is in the list of packages to be updated, it will get restarted after the update (at least this is what happens with Ubuntu, not sure for Amazon Linux) so there may be a small downtime (few seconds) for your users.

I always take an AMI image (with the No Reboot option checked) before installing updates. This way if something goes wrong I can quickly rollback the changes by launching the old image.

If you really don't want any donwtime at all, what you could do is to launch a second EC2 instance from an image of your current instance, install the updates on that new instance, and then switch the Elastic IP of the old instance to the new one. But then you need to make sure that your sessions are replicated or stored outside the instance itself, otherwise users will get logged out and loose their session.

Comment: I didn't mention it, but yes, creating a second instance is the other alternative. This is not a mission critical application, so if there are problems with the updates, I can always create a new instance from my AMI and deploy my war to it.

Comment: When Tomcat package is updated, are configuration files like server.xml and tomcat-users.xml overwritten? Thanks.